# What is the best practice for naming properties that are objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming-conventions

For example, is this a good practice?

```
private SalesOrder salesOrder;

public SalesOrder SalesOrder
{
    get { return salesOrder; }
    set { salesOrder = value; }
}
```

Or should I always append the object property with Object or BusinessObject to distinguish the property type from the property itself:

```
public SalesOrder SalesOrderBusinessObject
{
    get { return salesOrder; }
    set { salesOrder = value; }
}
```

Does it matter if the property is part of a web page or an object?

Comment: In the case I was thinking of its actually a user control.  The control is called SendEmail.ascx.  So then the usage would read `SendEmail.Order`

Comment: Then you should separate the UI from the business logic, create a class `Sale` (or whatever).

Comment: It is.  SalesOrder is a completely separate class, with its own set of properties and data access methods  I'm using this property to keep track of the SalesOrder across postbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is horrible. It's modelling something that has a sales order, which in turn is modelled by an object - not modelling something that has a sales order object.

"BusinessObject" should only be the name of something in your code, if you're writing a tool for developers to help them deal with business objects.

The former is often good.

It's not good if there could be more than one `SalesOrder` - even if one is the "main" one, you're introducing confusion. However a `SalesOrders` property that was an enumerable or collection of `SalesOrder` objects is good (when the English-language plural isn't of the singular + 's' form, use the real plural rather than just adding s, unless it's a case where the English plural is the same as the singular.

It's less than great when everything else is sales-related. E.g. this is horrible:

```
public class Sale
{
  public SalesOrder SalesOrder{get;set;}
  public SalesReference SalesReference{get;set;}
  public decimal SalesValue{get;set;}
  public string SalesCurrency{get;set;}
}
```

In this case I'd cut the "Sales" from each property name, but not (necessarily) from the class names.

However, this is a case where it's nicer:

```
public class Sale
{
  public SalesOrder SalesOrder{get;set;}
  public StockOrder StockOrder{get;set;}
}
```

In all, the way to approach it is:

1. What is the best name for what this class does, that differentiates it from what other classes do (and hence, no "object", "business object", "entity" or similar unless that really stands out as being particularly relevant in the given case).
2. What is the best name for what the property reflects, that differentiates it from other properties.

If they end up giving the same name in a particular case, then that's fine (unless it's a nested class, when it's ambiguous and illegal). If they end up giving a different name, then fine too.

Comment: The class is a user control, SendEmail that has a 1:1 relationship with `SalesOrder`.

Comment: I'd probably go with `SalesOrder` then. What is the class for? To represent a sales order. What is the property for? To hold the sales order the control is dealing with. Both questions suggest the answer "sales order", and applying .NET naming conventions to that gives `SalesOrder` separately in both cases.
If there's anything to critique, it would be the verb "send" applied to a thing (a control), but it's likely a perfectly reasonable abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put types in names.  Classes can change meanings over the course of their lifetime and you don't want your code growing but not reflecting what has changed.  This is a hold over from the ASP days when you used to prefix table names with 'tbl' and views with 'vw'.  Name the properties what they are, singular or plural, and just be consistent.  Just don't put what the class is in the name.  And if you are looking to more accurately reflect what the object is, look into domain driven design so that your code reflects the business instead of what programmers consider it.